# How to prevent /etc/rc.local from running twice?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, script

Here's my `/etc/rc.local` so far:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

/path/to/script.sh &

exit 0
```

And that's all it is.

The problem is that `script.sh` is running twice on startup according to its logfile.  The first run goes like it's supposed to, but the second spews a bunch of error messages because of things already started, etc.  If I run the script manually, it only goes once, so I'm sure it's not looping internally.

---

If I change `/etc/rc.local` to this:

```
date     >> /path/to/Debug.txt
runlevel >> /path/to/Debug.txt
#/path/to/script.sh &
```

then I get this in `Debug.txt` after one reboot:

```
Fri Jan  6 15:56:42 CST 2017
N 2
Fri Jan  6 15:58:38 CST 2017
N 2
```

Comment: Trying to understand why that happens. `This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel`. What is the output of `runlevel` command?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to find out why your script is getting called twice.  Is rc.local getting called twice, or is your script getting started from another location?  You could try adding some logging to rc.local to see if it is in fact what is getting called twice.  For example,

```
date >/var/tmp/rc.local.log
/path/to/script.sh &

exit 0
```

If you are unable to track down why your script is getting started twice, the other option is to create a lock file for your script.  This should go into a tmpfs filesystem so it will disappear on reboot.  Add something like this to the top of your script.

```
test -f /var/run/script.sh.pid && exit 0
echo $$ >/var/run/script.sh.pid
```

This way, if the `/var/run/script.sh.pid` exists, the script exits.  Otherwise it creates it and continues running it.  This solution is subject to races, but it might be enough to work around your issue.

Comment: I put your and @KamilMaciorowski's comments together and added that to the question.